# Partition sizes different in df and fdisk

Tags: partitioning, mount, disk-usage, lvm

I'm seeing different sizes using df vs fdisk commands. Please help!

> df -h

```
Filesystem                  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                         16G  4.0K   16G   1% /dev
tmpfs                       3.2G  820K  3.2G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/spar1--vg-root  9.7G  6.2G  3.1G  68% /
none                        4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                        5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                         16G     0   16G   0% /run/shm
none                        100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/sda1                   236M   41M  183M  19% /boot
```

> sudo fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/sda: 292.3 GB, 292326211584 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 35539 cylinders, total 570949632 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0009bd3a

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      499711      248832   83  Linux
/dev/sda2          501758   570947583   285222913    5  Extended
/dev/sda5          501760   570947583   285222912   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/spar1--vg-root: 54.5 GB, 54525952000 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 6629 cylinders, total 106496000 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/spar1--vg-root doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/spar1--vg-swap_1: 125.8 GB, 125829120000 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 15297 cylinders, total 245760000 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/spar1--vg-swap_1 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

Comment: You are looking at two different partition structures. Fdisk shows the physical partitions. But LVM is logical partitions over the physical partitions so all Linux tools show the logical partitions. LVM can even span multiple physical partitions, so the LVM has no relation to the physical partitions. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuDesktopLVM

Answer (score 0):

Resizing Partitions
You can extend a Logical Volume with:

sudo lvextend -L +5g foo/bar

This will add 5 GB to the bar Logical Volume in the foo Volume Group. You can specify an absolute size if you want instead of a relative size by omitting the leading +. The space is allocated from any free space anywhere in the bar Volume Group. If you have multiple Physical Volumes you can add the names of one or more of them to the end of the command to limit which ones should be used to satisfy the request.

After extending the Logical Volume you need to expand the filesystem to use the new space. For ext 3/4, you simply run:

sudo resize2fs /dev/foo/bar